# Excel: Counting Consecutive Values Paired With Time Stamp Proximity

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013

**My Problem**

A bit of background, I have access to a database that provides me with engine status codes for a vehicle with a time stamp. This engine status code is in decimal, but needs to be converted to binary to be read because each engine status (No Engine Speed, Engine Derate, and so on) are assigned to one of the sixteen bits. I have figured out how to convert these decimal values to binary, and then how to split up the binary string into individual cells. My data now looks like this: https://i.gyazo.com/359785dfe236b81d5545105dfc59a958.png.

That's just a sample, the values go on to row 8656. So, Column E has the time stamps, Column F has the engine status (in decimal, these change even if they do only look to have a value of 1 or 65 in the sample I provided), Column G is Column F converted into 16-bit binary, and Columns H to W are each individual bit of the string in Column G. The black box contains values that I needed to hide, they're used as part of the query to the aforementioned database.

Now, what I'd like to do is count the number of times both of the two following conditions are met for each column in Columns H through W: (1) the value in the column is 1 consecutively 5 times or more, and (2) the time stamps (in column E) for each of those consecutive events are within two minutes of each other. In this instance, an event that meets those conditions is considered an event where one of those engine statuses was actually active and not just a brief blip. I need to know this for each bit column. Ideally these functions would go in H3:W3, above the bit columns. For a point of reference, Number of Values is located in Cell E6.

**What I Tried**

I put together the following function for criteria (1), but it doesn't work. I get a #Value error.

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(W7:W8656=1,COLUMN(W7:W8656)),IF(W7:W8656<>1,COLUMN(W7:W8656)))>=5,1))
```

For the time stamps I have this:

```
=IF(E8 - TIMEVALUE("00:02:00")<E7,1,0)
```

It seems to work, but I don't quite know how I'd implement it. It would be paired with the first function in a single function (perhaps an AND()?)

**To Experiment**

I uploaded a sanitized version of my worksheet to Google Drive if you'd like to take a closer look at what I'm dealing with. Here's a link to that: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_fZnVjXU9YAdS1JRS1VSnFnbmM.

Edit 1:

Here is an example of the function that I'm using in column G.

```
=DEC2BIN(INT(F7/256),8)&DEC2BIN(MOD(F7,256),8)
```

And here's what I'm using to split the binary string:

For the first:

```
=VALUE(MID(G7,1,1))
```

For the second:

```
=VALUE(MID(G7,2,1))
```

And so on.

Comment: Do you care where in the bitstring the 5 consecutive 1's occur? To put it another way: Are you counting 5 consecutive 1's anywhere in the string and it doesn't matter where? Or are you counting 5 consecutive 1's ending with bit0, bit1, ... bit11 each as separate cases?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding you. The 5 consecutive 1s would appear in a single column within the H to W range. So Bit 1 is represented by the 0s and 1s in H7:H8656, and when a 1 is present that bit is active. That bit corresponds to a particular engine status. So what I want to do is count if there's five consecutive 1s in the Bit 1 column and then, as a separate count, five consecutive 1s in the Bit 2 column, and so on. All done it would look something like: [link](https://i.gyazo.com/df0c5e7cf06c154f793b710b45467167.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nickelcap, I had another go at it. This assumes that (a) time-stamp data are in a column starting at $C$7; (b) engine status codes are in a column starting at $D$7, and (c) data can extend down as far as row 8656.

A. Define the minimum acceptable time interval (2 minutes). In cell X1 enter:

```
=TIME(0,2,0)
```

B. Create a column of delta-time data in column X (setting the value to zero when there is no data). In cell X8 enter:

```
=IF(LEN(TRIM($C8))=0,0,$C8-$C7)
```

and fill down this formula to row 8656.

C. Create a column of binary-formatted engine status codes. This is the same formula you came up with, wrapped in a filter to set the status code to all zeros if there is no data. In cell G7 enter:

```
=IF(LEN(TRIM(D7))>0,DEC2BIN(INT(D7/256),8)&DEC2BIN(MOD(D7,256),8),"0000000000000‌​000")
```

and fill down this formula to row 8658.

D. The range H7:W8658 has the same formula you came up with to extract a single bit. E.g. in H7:

```
=VALUE(MID($G7,1,1))
```

E. Finally, the formula for counting repeating failure codes. To count failures of the column H events I have this in H4:

```
=SUM(IF(IF($X$8:$X$8653<=$X$1,1,0)+IF($X$9:$X$8654<=$X$1,1,0)+IF($X$10:$X$8655<=$X$1,1,0)+IF($X$11:$X$8656<=$X$1,1,0)>=4,IF(H$7:H$8652+H$8:H$8653+H$9:H$8654+H$10:H$8655+H$11:H$8656>=5,1,0),0))
```

(It doesn't have to be in row 4 --- put it where you want.) Fill that formula across to column W.

One the spreadsheet is set up, you can clear out the old data and copy/paste new data in columns C and D to analyze the new data.

Hope that gets you going.

Comment: I've been testing this solution and seem to be getting false positives with the final formula. For example, [here](https://i.gyazo.com/3d0224244e112163b83bae73228e975d.png) I'm getting three 'Not Used' events but looking through the 1s below it I don't see any events that meet the criteria of at least 5 repeated 1s with time stamps that are within two minutes of the one prior to it. I'm not sure if I did something wrong implementing it or if there's an issue with the formula. As far as I can tell it looks like it should work. Any suggestions?

Comment: OK. I think I misunderstood your requirements. I mistakenly assumed you wanted the time interval to be at least 2 minutes. I now see that you want the time interval to be 2 minutes or less. If that's the case, change all the occurrences of >=$X$1 to <=$X$1 in formula E. You should be able to safely use Find/Replace.

Comment: Aha, now it seems to be working! Thank you for the help. I'll keep verifying, but so far it looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I think this might work for you. To determine for 5 consecutive bits, you can add the column of bits to itself 5 times (the start and end points are each offset by one row:

```
=W7:W8654+W8:W8655+W9:W8656+W10:W8657+W11:W8658
```

This will give you a vector with values 0-5 depending on the number of 1's in 5 bits of data. Then to test for the number of occurrences of 5 consecutive 1's:

```
=SUM(IF(W7:W8654+W8:W8655+W9:W8656+W10:W8657+W11:W8658=5,1,0))
```

entered as an array formula (CTRL-ENTER).

The same sort of logic works for finding 4 (not 5 -- don't get fooled by an off-by-one error!) consecutive time intervals that are 2 minutes or longer. This formula calculates how many 2-minute intervals there are in 4 consecutive intervals:

```
=IF(E8:E8655-E7:E8654>=TIME(0,2,0),1,0)+IF(E9:E8656-E8:E8655>=TIME(0,2,0),1,0)+IF(E10:E8657-E9:E8656>=TIME(0,2,0),1,0)+IF(E11:E8658-E10:E8657>=TIME(0,2,0),1,0)
```

To detect 4-consecutive 2-minute intervals, you again use the =SUM(IF(...)) formula:

```
=SUM(IF(IF(E8:E8655-E7:E8654>=TIME(0,2,0),1,0)+IF(E9:E8656-E8:E8655>=TIME(0,2,0),1,0)+IF(E10:E8657-E9:E8656>=TIME(0,2,0),1,0)+IF(E11:E8658-E10:E8657>=TIME(0,2,0),1,0)=4,1,0))
```

These two tests can be combined into one big formula for counting when consecutive 1-bits and consecutive 2-minute test intervals occur simultaneously.

```
=SUM(IF(IF(E8:E8655-E7:E8654>=TIME(0,2,0),1,0)+IF(E9:E8656-E8:E8655>=TIME(0,2,0),1,0)+IF(E10:E8657-E9:E8656>=TIME(0,2,0),1,0)+IF(E11:E8658-E10:E8657>=TIME(0,2,0),1,0)=4,IF(W7:W8654+W8:W8655+W9:W8656+W10:W8657+W11:W8658=5,1,0),0))
```

By the way, the time-side of the test could be significantly simplified by testing for 8-minutes from start to end of the consecutive 1 bits and ignoring the internal test intervals. That change might flag more test failures, so you'd need to assess whether the additional failures are real or not.

This solutions is a bit messy, so I hope I've explained it well enough and hope it's helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried your formula with the two tests combined and received a #VALUE error. I tried both components separately and had the same issue. I made sure to hit Ctrl-Enter but no dice. Jon posted a solution that seems to work, but as he said in his post it is cumbersome.

Comment: nickelcap, the formula I posted worked on a simulation data set that I generated. I downloaded your sample data from googledocs and reproduced the error you describe. The error occurs because my solution assumed that valid data extends to row 8658. In your data, the last several thousand rows are filled with #VALUE, which caused my formula (and yours!) to return #VALUE. When I either (a) modified my formula to a shorter input range, or (b) kept the original formula and cleaned the data by replacing #VALUE's with zeroes AND extending the time data with valid entries, my formula worked.

Comment: Ah, I see. The issue is that in my worksheet those rows that have #VALUE errors are like that because of the functions I'm using to first convert from decimal to binary, and then take that binary stream and split it into bits across sixteen columns. Those functions need to stay in those rows up to 8658, even if they do return a #VALUE, because the data query that gives the date stamps and decimal engine status could return up to that many values. I'll make an edit to my post so you can see my functions. Could they be modified to work with your formula?

Comment: One way to make this work is to overwrite the missing data with zeros --- one manual step and you're done. You could also "wrap a filter" around your formula: =IF(LEN(TRIM(F7))>0,DEC2BIN(INT(F7/256),8)&DEC2BIN(MOD(F7,256),8),"0000000000000000") which sets the value to all zeros when the data is missing. You also would need to filter the time data. A good way to do that is to add a new calculated column of delta_time. When there is data, delta_time = current_time - previous_time; when the data is missing, delta_time = 0. My formula would need modification to change from absolute to delta time.

Comment: Hmm... I think I did what you suggested but in a different way. I pushed the database query over two columns and populated the newly vacant columns with two IFERROR formulas that return either the value from the data query or 0 if there's an error. Still, the formula wouldn't work for me. I updated the file in Google Drive if you'd like to take a look. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I'll preface this by saying I didn't use array formulae for this so it could almost certainly be simplified.

Note to avoid having #REF errors or formulas that change depending on row number, I've made the row headers appear on row 5, with the first row of data appearing in row 6. I've also sorted the data based on timestamp (column E). This is important or step 2 below doesn't work.

My approach is to use a shedload of helper columns. I've split the problem into four separate tests on the data, each of which takes 16 columns (one for each bit). In all cases each formula is copied down to the bottom of the data and across into each block of 16 columns.

1. Test if a condition is consecutively 1 five times in a row

Columns X to AM - formula (X6): `=IF(SUM(H2:H6)=5,1,0)` (copy across columns X:AM, down to the bottom of the dataset)

2. Test if the previous 5 results all occur within a 2 minute window

Columns AN to BC - formula (AN6): `=IF(SUM($E6)-SUM($E2)<2/(24*60),1,0)` (copy across columns AN:BC, down to the bottom of the dataset)

3. Test if both of the above conditions occur on the same row

Columns BD to BS - formula (BD6): `=IF(AND(X6=1,AN6=1),1,0)` (copy across columns BD:BS, down to the bottom of the dataset)

4. Where both conditions occur, discard any adjacent positive results (so if a stretch of 5 "1"s in 1 minute and 30 seconds has another 1 15 seconds later, it's still counted as a single instance.

Columns BT to CI - formula (BT6): `=IF(AND(BD6=1,BD5<>1),1,0)` (copy across columns BT:CI, down to to the bottom of the dataset)

Finally, you can check for the number of instances per 16 test bits by doing the following:

Cells H1 to W1 - formula (H1): `=COUNTIF(BT6:BT10628,1)`
Note the end row of this formula will need to be changed depending on the size of your data.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Just to add, I wasn't entirely certain that you meant for me to copy the first 4 formulas down so I was a bit confused at first. Once I did that the fifth formula worked as expected.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've made the instructions a bit more explicit. Don't forget you can upvote answers (I wouldn't mark this as the correct answer just yet as there may be a way to do this in a single array formula)